# microsoft word case insensitive find and replace with wildcards

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, regex, find-and-replace, wildcards

When enabling the wildcards option in a find and replace operation, it automatically becomes case sensitive.  Is there a way to allow a wildcard search such that something like: 
`example*find*and*replace`

would find all of

- *EXAMPLEFINDAND REPLACE*
- *Example find and Replace*
- *example FinD and-Replace*
- *Example, find this and replace It*

?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way seems to be to enclose each character in square brackets like: `[L,l][I,i][K,k][E,e] [T,t][H,h][I,i][S,s]`.

even with vba

```
selection.find
.MatchWildcards = True
.MatchCase = False
```

It doesn't work.